# Android studio Android app runtime configuration module not shown

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I cannot see any modules for my android app in the runtime configurations of Android studio. I am not sure if this a gradle error either. This is my build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub- 
projects/modules.
buildscript {
   repositories {
      google()
}
dependencies {
    def nav_version = "2.5.1"
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
 }

}


plugins {
   id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
   id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[image]

Also, the java files icons are red too. How can I fix this? Please help, many thanks!